# Gradle jar does not include Guava Preconditions

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, guava

I have the following build.gradle file for my project

```
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:23.6-jre';
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'Runner.ClientRunner'
    }
}
```

However, when I run "gradle jar" and attempt to run the given jar, I get the error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Preconditions
```

I can't seem to nail down what I've done wrong here, guava is included in the dependencies for gradle and the jar file appears to build fine otherwise (it only crashes when it gets to the first class that depends on guava). Any assistance appreciated.
If it helps I'm doing this from IntelliJ.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem using the solution at https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-include-dependencies-in-jar/19571

My build.gradle now looks like

```
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

configurations {
    // configuration that holds jars to include in the jar
    extraLibs
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:23.6-jre';
    extraLibs group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '23.6-jre'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    configurations.compile.extendsFrom(configurations.extraLibs)
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'Runner.ClientRunner'
    }
    from {
        configurations.extraLibs.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
}
```